# função strcpy não funciona no Linux

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void envia(char* pdados);

int main()
{
char* link[1000];
strcpy(link,"http://site.com/data.php?dados=");

char* dados = "name";

strcat(link,dados);

//printf("%s\n",link);
envia(link);
}

void envia(char *pdados){
printf("%s\n",pdados);

char comando[2000];
sprintf(comando, "curl %s >> /dev/null", pdados);
system(comando);
}
```

ERRO:

> ```
> manda.c: In function ‘main’:
> manda.c:9:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   strcpy(link,"http://site.com/data.php?dados=");
>   ^
> In file included from manda.c:2:0:
> /usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
>  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
>               ^
> manda.c:13:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcat’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   strcat(link,dados);
>   ^
> In file included from manda.c:2:0:
> /usr/include/string.h:137:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
> ```

Comment: Ao invés de `char* link[1000];`, que tal tentar `char link[1000];`, ou seja, sem o `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como link foi declarado como ponteiro (de um array de char), portanto a variável link (ou a link[0]) representam um ponteiro de ponteiro (char **), pois ambas sozinhas (sem a declaração como ponteiro) indicam um ponteiro para o começo do array de char. 
Então ao invés de usar `char* link[1000]` utilizar `char link[1000]`.
Pois a função strcpy recebe um char * e não um char **, O mesmo vale para o strcat.

Answer (score 0):

**Alterei o tipo de dados da função, e agora está funcionando, obrigado pela ajuda**

```
void envia(char *pdados)
{
    char* dados = pdados;

    char* resultado;
    size_t  len;

    len = (size_t)("http://site.com/data.php?dados=");
    resultado = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));

    strncpy(resultado, "site.com/data.php?dados=", len);

    strcat(resultado,dados);
    //printf("%s\n",resultado);

    char comando[2000];
    sprintf(comando, "curl -s %s >> /dev/null &", resultado);
    system(comando);
}
```

Comment: Atenção: o strcat não tem alocado o espaço necessário para receber os "dados".

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void envia(char *pdados) {
   char comando[1000];
   sprintf(comando, "curl -s '%s%s' > /dev/null",     
             "http://site.com/data.php?dados=", pdados);
   system(comando);
}

int main(){
   envia("aaa");
   return 0;
}
```